# VGA monitor doesn't work at boot time on Mac mini 2011

Tags: mac, vga

I have Mac mini 2011 and Samsung Syncmaster 710v (old TFT monitor) connected through mini DisplayPort to VGA. The monitor shows something only when the login screen appears (no boot menu, no boot-loading, just black screen, BUT no info that the monitor isn't connected).

On new monitors (VGA), my Mac works great and I can see the boot menu. Is it the monitor's problem, a mini DisplayPort issue, or software?

Comment: Do you have multiple monitors connected to the Mac Mini when you are attempting to get the VGA display to work?

Comment: no, i haven't. only tft monitor.

Answer (score -1):

Could be something to do with the energy save technology and standy mode on old tft monitors, if your monitor has energy save.

Probably that's not 100% compatible with new Macs.